# How to solve the error: "The type or namespace name 'BITMAPFILEHEADER' could not be found"?

Tags: c#

I need to write a file (BMP format). The program should: • load and display an arbitrary file on the screen (using file functions);

• check for a valid file format;

• read up to 256 colors (black / white, gray, 16,256);

• display information from file headers (type, size, resolution, use of compression, number of colors, ...), as well as a color palette;

• provide scrolling image.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.ComponentModel;

using System.Data;

using System.Drawing;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace Project1

{

public partial class Form1: Form

{



[DllImport ("winmm.dll")]

private static extern long mciSendString (string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);



private string sCommand = "";

public int k;

public string path;

public Color [] pixel;

public Form1 ()

{

this.components = ((IContainer) null);

this.path = "";

this.k = 0;

this.InitializeComponent ();

error = new error ();

Zooom = new Zooom ();

            }

// error error;

// Zooom Zooom;





private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{

this.label1.Visible = false;

this.label2.Visible = false;

this.label3.Visible = false;

this.label4.Visible = false;

this.label5.Visible = false;

this.label7.Visible = false;

this.label8.Visible = false;

this.listView2.Visible = false;

this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog ();

if (dialog.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK)

{

this.path = dialog.FileName;

FileStream stream = new FileStream (this.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // synchronous and asynchronous write and read

byte [] buffer = new byte [Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))]; // memory allocation for unmanaged code

stream.Read (buffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))); // read bytes from the stream and write data to the specified buffer

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc (buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned); // access to a managed object from unmanaged memory

BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapfileheader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER) Marshal.PtrToStructure (handle.AddrOfPinnedObject (), typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER)); // transfer from unmanaged to managed memory

handle.Free ();

if (bitmapfileheader.bfType == 0x4d42)

{

this.k ++;

}

else

{

sCommand = "open \" "+ @" D: \ 1.mp3 "+" \ "type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";

                                                                          // send a command

                                                                          mciSendString (sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

                                                                          // command to play the file

                                                                          sCommand = "play MediaFile";

                                                                          // send a command

                                                                          mciSendString (sCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

                                                                          error.ShowDialog ();

}

}

}



private void viewToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (this.k <= 0)

{

this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

}

else

{

int num8;

int num9;

int num10;

int num11;

this.label1.Visible = false;

this.label2.Visible = false;

this.label3.Visible = false;

this.label4.Visible = false;

this.label5.Visible = false;

this.label7.Visible = false;

this.label8.Visible = false;

this.listView1.Visible = false;

this.AutoScroll = false;

char [,] chArray = new char [256, 4]; // 256

char [] chArray2 = new char [1024]; // 1024

FileStream stream = new FileStream (this.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte [] buffer1 = new byte [Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))];

stream.Read (buffer1, 0, Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER)));

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc (buffer1, GCHandleType.Pinned);

BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapfileheader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER) Marshal.PtrToStructure (handle.AddrOfPinnedObject (), typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER));

handle.Free ();

int biBitCount = bitmapfileheader.biBitCount;

this.AutoScroll = true;

this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

int x = 0;

int y = 0;

int index = 0;

Color [] colorArray = new Color [256]; // 256

int biWidth = bitmapfileheader.biWidth;

int biHeight = bitmapfileheader.biHeight;

int num7 = bitmapfileheader.biWidth + (((bitmapfileheader.biWidth% 4) == 0)? 0: (4 - (bitmapfileheader.biWidth% 4)));

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap (biWidth +2, biHeight + 2);

switch (bitmapfileheader.biBitCount)

{

case 1:

{

index = 0;

while (index <(((int) 1) << bitmapfileheader.biBitCount))

{

num8 = stream.ReadByte ();

num9 = stream.ReadByte ();

num10 = stream.ReadByte ();

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

colorArray [index] = Color.FromArgb (255, num10, num9, num8);

index ++;

}

index = 0;

x = 0;

y = biHeight;

int ReadInString = 0; // read bits in string

int ReadGroupByte = 0; // read bytes in a group of 4

for (index = 0; stream.Position <stream.Length; index + = 1)

{

ReadGroupByte ++;

if (ReadGroupByte == 4)

ReadGroupByte = 0;

if (ReadInString == biWidth)

{

ReadInString = 0;

x = 0; y--;

if (y <0)

break;

index + = 4 - ReadGroupByte;

ReadGroupByte = 0;

continue;

}

else // not all bits have been read in the string yet.

{

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

for (int j = 0; j <8; j ++)

{

if (ReadInString == biWidth)

{

x = 0; y--;

break;}



int indexBit = ((num11 >> (7 - j)) & 1);

ReadInString ++;

bitmap.SetPixel (x, y, colorArray [indexBit]);

x ++;

}

}

}

                  break;

}





case 2:

index = 0;

while (index <(((int) 1) << bitmapfileheader.biBitCount))

{

num8 = stream.ReadByte ();

num9 = stream.ReadByte ();

num10 = stream.ReadByte ();

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

colorArray [index] = Color.FromArgb (0xff, num10, num9, num8);

index ++;

}

for (index = 0; stream.Position <stream.Length; index ++)

{

x = index% num7; // assignment of balance

y = biHeight - (index / num7);

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

x = index% num7;

y = biHeight - (index / num7);

bitmap.SetPixel (x, y, colorArray [num11]);

}

break;

case 4:

index = 0;

while (index <(((int) 1) << bitmapfileheader.biBitCount))

{

num8 = stream.ReadByte ();

num9 = stream.ReadByte ();

num10 = stream.ReadByte ();

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

colorArray [index] = Color.FromArgb (0xff, num10, num9, num8);

index ++;

}

index = 0;

while (stream.Position <stream.Length)

{

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

x = index% num7;

y = biHeight - (index / num7);

bitmap.SetPixel (x, y, colorArray [num11 >> 4]);

bitmap.SetPixel (x + 1, y, colorArray [num11 & 15]);

index + = 2;

}

break;

case 8:

for (index = 0; index <(((int) 1) << bitmapfileheader.biBitCount); index ++)

{

num8 = stream.ReadByte ();

num9 = stream.ReadByte ();

num10 = stream.ReadByte ();

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

colorArray [index] = Color.FromArgb (0xff, num10, num9, num8); // 0xff - 255

}

index = 0;

while (stream.Position <stream.Length)

{

num11 = stream.ReadByte ();

x = index% num7;

y = biHeight - (index / num7);

bitmap.SetPixel (x, y, colorArray [num11]);

index ++;

}

break;



case 24:

while (stream.Position <stream.Length)

{

num8 = stream.ReadByte ();

num9 = stream.ReadByte ();

num10 = stream.ReadByte ();

x = index% num7;

y = biHeight - (index / num7);

bitmap.SetPixel (x, y, Color.FromArgb (0xff, num10, num9, num8));

index ++;

}

break;

}

this.pictureBox1.Width = bitmapfileheader.biWidth;

this.pictureBox1.Height = bitmapfileheader.biHeight;

this.pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

bitmap.Save ("1.bmp");

}



}



private void pictureBox1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{



}



private void infoToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (this.k <= 0)

{

this.label1.Visible = false;

this.label2.Visible = false;

this.label3.Visible = false;

this.label4.Visible = false;

this.label5.Visible = false;

this.label7.Visible = false;

this.label8.Visible = false;

this.listView2.Visible = false;

this.AutoScroll = false;

}

else

{

this.label1.Visible = true;

this.label2.Visible = true;

this.label3.Visible = true;

this.label4.Visible = true;

this.label5.Visible = true;

this.label7.Visible = true;

this.label8.Visible = true;

this.listView2.Visible = false;

this.AutoScroll = true;

this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

string [] strArray = new string [10];

FileStream stream = new FileStream (this.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte [] buffer = new byte [Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))];

stream.Read (buffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER)));

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc (buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapfileheader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER) Marshal.PtrToStructure (handle.AddrOfPinnedObject (), typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER));

handle.Free ();

if (bitmapfileheader.bfType == 19778)

{

this.label8.Text = "Path and filename:" + stream.Name;

this.label1.Text = "File Type: BMP";

this.label2.Text = "File size:" + bitmapfileheader.bfSize.ToString () + "(byte)";

this.label3.Text = "Image height:" + bitmapfileheader.biHeight.ToString ();

this.label4.Text = "Image width:" + bitmapfileheader.biWidth.ToString ();

switch (bitmapfileheader.biBitCount)

{

case 1:

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: 2";

break;

case 24:

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: the palette is not used, each three byte of the image represents one pixel, byte for the intensity of the blue, green and red channels, respectively";

break;



case 32:

if (bitmapfileheader.biCompression == 0)

{

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: the image does not contain a palette";

}

else

{

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: Every four bytes of the image represent one pixel, byte for the intensity of the blue, green and red channels, respectively";

}

break;



case 8:

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: The palette contains up to 256 colors, each byte of the image stores an index in the palette for one pixel";

break;



case 16:

if (bitmapfileheader.biCompression == 0)

{

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: the image does not contain a palette";

}

else

{

this.label5.Text = "Number of colors: Every two bytes of the image store the intensity of the red, green and blue components of one pixel";

}

break;

}

switch (bitmapfileheader.biCompression)

{

case 0:

this.label7.Text = "Compression Type: Uncompressed Image";

break;



case 1:

this.label7.Text = "Compression type: RLE compression for 8-bit images";

break;



case 2:

this.label7.Text = "Compression type: RLE compression for 4-bit images";

break;



case 4:

this.label7.Text = "Compression Type: Win98 / Me / 2000 / XP: JPEG Compression";

break;



case 5:

this.label7.Text = "Compression Type: Win98 / Me / 2000 / XP: PNG Compression";

break;



case 6:

this.label7.Text = "Compression type: WinCE: the image is not compressed, the palette contains four 4-byte masks for the red, green, blue and transparent (alpha channel) color component. Used for 16-bit and 32-bit images";

break;

}

}

}



}



private void colorToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (this.k> 0)

{

int num2;

int num3;

int num4;

int num5;

this.label1.Visible = false;

this.label2.Visible = false;

this.label3.Visible = false;

this.label4.Visible = false;

this.label5.Visible = false;

this.label7.Visible = false;

this.label8.Visible = false;

this.pictureBox1.Visible = false;

this.listView2.Visible = true;

this.listView2.Clear ();

string [] strArray = new string [10];

FileStream stream = new FileStream (this.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

byte [] buffer = new byte [Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER))];

stream.Read (buffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER)));

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc (buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapfileheader = (BITMAPFILEHEADER) Marshal.PtrToStructure (handle.AddrOfPinnedObject (), typeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER));

handle.Free ();

int num = 0;

int num6 = 0;

switch (bitmapfileheader.biBitCount)

{

case 4:

while (stream.Position <1078)

{

num2 = stream.ReadByte ();

num3 = stream.ReadByte ();

num4 = stream.ReadByte ();

num5 = stream.ReadByte ();

this.listView2.Items.Add (Convert.ToString (num6));

this.listView2.Items [num6] .BackColor = Color.FromArgb (num5, num4, num3, num2);

num6 ++;

num ++;

}

break;



case 8:

{



while (stream.Position <1078)

{

num2 = stream.ReadByte ();

num3 = stream.ReadByte ();

num4 = stream.ReadByte ();

num5 = stream.ReadByte ();

this.listView2.Items.Add (Convert.ToString (num6));

this.listView2.Items [num6] .BackColor = Color.FromArgb (num5, num4, num3, num2);

num6 ++;

num ++;

}

break;

}

case 24:

MessageBox.Show ("No Palette!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);

break;

}

}



}



private void label8_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{



}



private void zoomToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

{

Zooom.Show ();

}



private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)

{



}



}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're doing an interop. [BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmapfileheader) is not a C# structure but a C++ you have to create one in C# inorder to make use

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=2)]
public struct BITMAPFILEHEADER
{
     public ushort bfType; 
     public uint bfSize; 
     public ushort bfReserved1; 
     public ushort bfReserved2; 
     public uint bfOffBits; 
}
```

You should take a look at pinvoke.net and MSDN docs for more info
https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.BITMAPFILEHEADER

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-tagbitmapfileheader

**I would suggest you to take a look at the [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2) class in C#. This ones uses the GDI.**